# Initialization of array

Tags: java, arrays

What is the problem with the following code?

```
class xyz
    {
      int[] array=new int[3];
      array[0]=0;
      array[1]=1;
      array[2]=2;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   xyz a=new xyz();
   System.out.println(a.array[0]+" "+a.array[1]+" "+a.array[2]);
   }
  }
```

I am not able to initialize the array within the class but it works if it is initialized within a method of the class or the main function.

Comment: you need a constructor

Comment: You can not randomly place code statements in the class, without them being in some method/constructor/block in Java.

Comment: I don't think that's a good duplicate; the issue isn't the initialization functionality, but where it's trying to live.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to declare and initialize an array can be done in a single statement, like

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 2 };
```

**or** you can use an initialization block. Like,

```
int[] array=new int[3];
{
    array[0]=0;
    array[1]=1;
    array[2]=2;
}
```

Comment: Isn’t the second part of this not what OP has already, albeit outside of a method?

Comment: @notyou Yes, ***but*** OP's assignment statements **aren't** in an initialization block.

Comment: yeah the OP is clearly trying to figure out how to make an instance of the object with a constructor doing the legwork for the array, I don't think this answer is what he was looking for

Comment: Ah - I didn’t see that.

Comment: @aquaballin One distinction: an initialization block is **copied** into every constructor. So you would have to copy-and-paste this manually into every constructor for it to be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

```
array[0]=0;
array[1]=1;
array[2]=2;
```

This is not legal Java. Executable code must be inside a method or constructor.